# Multiple dynamic url redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have looked at many similar questions bu they don't approach the real problem. I would like to redirect a user to a certain url just after login depending on a condition about the user.

I know this can be archieved with a middleware so I have tried this in app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::User()->check()) {
            $redirect = '/client';
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
                $redirect = '/admin';
            }
            return redirect($redirect);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I realise now this will not work just after login. I'd like to redirect a user depending whether he/she is an admin or a client. I know I could use: protected $redirectPath = '/url/to/redirect'; but I have multiple pages to redirect to.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could over-write the redirect method offered up by the trait in **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php**

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
        return '/admin';
    }

    return '/client';
}
```

Put that in your AuthController.php.

Comment: No problem :) @user5500750